# changing html text colors with css

Tags: html, css

I have the following html snippet:

```
<a href="page1.aspx" class="title">page title goes here</a><br />
<span class="username">username goes here: </span><span class="dateandtime">date the time go here</span>
```

Here is the css for these classes

```
.title
{
    color:#707070;
}

.username
{
    color:#8DAAB8;
}

.dateandtime
{
    color:#A5A7AC;
}
```

Is it possible to change the colors of these 3 items when hovering over the title?

The colors I want the items to change to are as follows

```
title = 000000
username = DF821B
dateandtime = 3185B6
```

Not sure if this is possible with css, if the html snippet structure needs to change, that will not be a problem.

I know this can be done with javascript, but wanted to know if it is possible without javascript.

Comment: use hover in css like `.title:hover { color : 000000}`

Comment: if you want to change all 3 on hovering of 1 of them then you may need JavaScript to achieve it. Only CSS will not work for you.

Comment: @Harry Joy, I had a feeling it would be that way.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not totally clear on the question -- do you want each of them to have their own hover colour, or do you want all three to change colour at once, when you hover on any of them?

In the first case, it's easy: just add a `:hover` style for each of the three elements (you already have answers to this effect, so I won't repeat them here).

In the second case, you'll need a container element that would take the hover, so your code would look like this:

```
<span class='container'>
    <a href="page1.aspx" class="title">page title goes here</a><br />
    <span class="username">username goes here: </span><span class="dateandtime">date the time go here</span>
</span>
```

(you may want to use `<div>` rather than `<span>`, but I'll leave that up to you)

Your CSS would then look like this:

```
.title {color:#707070;}
.username {color:#8DAAB8;}
.dateandtime {color:#A5A7AC;}

.container:hover .title {color:#000000;}
.container:hover .username {color:#DF821B;}
.container:hover .dateandtime {color:#3185B6;}
```

Obviously, change the colours in the new styles to whatever you want them to be. If all three should be the same, then you could simplify the three new styles down to something like this:

```
.container:hover span, .container:hover a, {color:#000000;}
```

Hope that helps.

One final thing to note: IE6 and below do not support the `:hover` style on anything except `<a>` elements. My recommendation to you is simply not to support IE6 for your site (there are plenty of other things broken in IE6 too), but if you do need to support it, there are hacks available to get `:hover` to work with it. See [Whatever:Hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html).

Comment: I mean the second one, i.e. want all three to change colour at once.  I tried your script and it does not work at all for some reason.  Did copy and paste.  Tried it in ie8, fx4, and chromium.

Comment: @oshirowanen - sorry; I missed out the dots on the classnames. Fixed it, and I've tested that it works.

Comment: I think it is only fair to accept this answer as according to Steven Don, you suggested it first.

Comment: @oshirowanen: thank you  :)  and @Steven Don: thanks for your honesty. (I'll give you +1 as well though, for suggesting the ~ selector... I like to think I'm quite good with CSS, but I've never actually used the ~ selector)

Comment: Works in ie7.  Don't have access to ie6.

Comment: @oshirowanen - If you ever want to know what CSS works in which browser, there's a very good summary here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 4):

Use the :hover pseudoclass:

```
.title:hover
{
    color: #000000;
}
```

etc. This works in all browsers, except in IE6 and earlier, which doesn't support :hover on anything other than hyperlinks (A elements).

**Edit 1**: I see you want to change them all while hovering over the title. In that case, it becomes a little more complicated. You should put a <div> around it and apply the :hover pseudoclass on that. It won't just be the title (which is also possible, but has even less chance of working in IE). For that:

```
<div class="someclass"><a href="#" class="title">Title</a><span class="username">username</span><span class="dateandtime">date and time</span></div>
```

is your HTML, but your CSS would be:

```
.someclass .title:hover { color: #000000; }
.someclass .title:hover ~ .username { color: #DF821B; }
.someclass .title:hover ~ .dateandtime { color: #3185B6; }
```

Where ~ is the sibling selector (meaning it should have the same parent (.someclass) as the .title:hover).

@Harry Joy: No, it's not. My answer is different, not to mention I don't have enough rep to post comments.

**Edit 2**:
As requested, to make them all change while hovering over the entire container, use the above HTML with the following CSS:

```
.someclass:hover .title { color: #000000; }
.someclass:hover .username { color: #DF821B; }
.someclass:hover .dateandtime { color: #3185B6; }
```

(though basically credit for that goes to Spudley for suggesting it first).

Comment: @Steven: one's comment is another's answer.

Comment: @Steven Don, thanks, I will give this a try now.  And yes, I want all of them to change at the same time just by hovering over the title.  If all of them change by hovering over any of them, that is even better!

Comment: To change them all by hovering over any of them, just apply the :hover psuedoclass to the .someclass div, like Spudley suggests.

Comment: This works in ie8, fx4, but not in chrome.  Any chance you could edit your answer to include the hover over all items.  I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I could't get the script posted by Spudley to work at all, but what you have now posted seems to work in ie8, fx4, and chromium.  Thanks.

Comment: I think it is only fair to accept I accept Spudley's answer as he suggested it first rightly pointed out by you.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible, just append this to your CSS:

```
.title:hover
{
    color:#000000;
}

.username:hover
{
    color:#DF821B;
}

.dateandtime:hover
{
    color:#3185B6;
}
```

This called a pseudo-class and will make your anchors change color when hovered )

**Edit:**

At first I misunderstood your question, this isn't the solution!

You can't do this in CSS alone, but you can do it jQuery easily!

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/PmusY/).

What you need to do is set up a class for each of the hovered states, then use jQuery to replace add a class that will change the colors as you want :)

You just have to include the jQuery framework if you haven't already:

In the `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please read my reply to Harry Joy in the comments section directly below my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do this one of two ways but not with CSS, you can either add and remove the appropriate classes (unobtrusive JavaScript) or change the styles directly. For instance:

```
document.getElementById('someElement').style.color = '#FF0000';
```

Or you can use a JavaScript library such as jQuery.

```
jQuery('p.someClass').mouseOver(function(e) {
    e.target.style.color = '#FF0000';
})
.mouseOut(function(e) {
    e.target.style.color = '#000000';
});
```

Comment: The comment Harry Joy made is the best solution, use the CSS hover pseudo selector.

Comment: @Kyle I know, because it is not possible with CSS. He wants it so when you mouse over one element it changes all of them.

Comment: @Wolfy87, @Kyle : i also interpret same as Wolfy87. that he wants to change all 3 while hovering on 1 of them.

Comment: @Wolfy87 - it is still possible with CSS, even if you want all three to change colour; just have a container element for all three which has the `:hover` style. I'll post an answer to that effect...

Comment: But then it will occur when you mouse over any of them, he said specifically the title will change the others. He is basically wondering something I tried to do a long time ago, changing another elements styles by pseudo classes on another element. Which is not possible with pure CSS.

Comment: @Wolfy87 - in his case, it seems like it can be done with CSS, since it seems he wants all three to change at once. Agree with you that changing un-related elements isn't possible in CSS, though.

Comment: It is using some funky tide selector, which after a bit of reading turns out to be fairly temperamental when it comes to cross browser. You will have to use JavaScript eventually mate.

Comment: @Wolfy87, his new version "edit 2" seems to work without those funky tide selectors, and works in ie8, fx4, and chromium.